# Selecting the next sibling of the item just clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` which contains images. These images are profile images fetched from twitter and appended into the `ul` dynamically. Once the user clicks on any of the images, I need to also cache the node of the image right next to it (the next sibling). I tried using the `next()` selector like below, but what gets logged in the console is a message I do not understand. Here is the code:

```
$("ul#container").on("click", "img", function(){
  var nextImage = $(this).next();
  console.log(nextImage);
}
```

Here is what gets logged in the console:

> [prevObject: p.fn.p.init[1], context: , selector: ".next ()"]

Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks for reading!

Comment: That's a jQuery object and contains one element. You should be able to work with that in code.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong.

That is how Chrome now logs jQuery objects.

Now go have some fun with it!

Comment: The logging of jQuery objects was much better in previous versions of Chrome.

Comment: @pimvdb yea... now it is quite confusing... before it actually showed you the element... How do you make it log the element now?....

Comment: The only hack I've found is running `console.log = inspect;` in the console. But that's cumbersome.

Comment: What? No it isn't. What version of Chrome are you guys running?

Comment: You can get the Dom Element by doing `console.log($('div')[0]);` or you can convert it back to jQuery by wrapping it again ​​​​`console.log($($('div')[0]));` http://jsfiddle.net/uhURd/

Comment: Alright Neal! Indeed it seems I was trying to fix something that wasn't broken anyway! Each img was also wrapped in its own <li>. Thus indeed there were no other images within the li. Lesson for the future: I will also be posting the HTML in my questions. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("ul#container").on("click", "img", function(){
  var nextImage = $(this).next().get(0);
  console.log(nextImage);
}
```

Or

**[Try This Plugin For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/consolelog-output-real-ht/jnfjicjapkamepnbiplhcjhcjccmegna)**