# How do I console.log a jQuery DOM Element in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, logging

I used to be able to do `console.log(somejQueryObj);` and it logged in an array all of the DOM elements that are in the object that I could click and go to the inspector.

Now it does something like this:

> [prevObject: p.fn.p.init[1], context: , selector: ".next ()"]

which can confuse [many people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13974644/561731).

How do I make it so that Chrome logs how it used to log jQuery elements?

[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/MmrRr/)

---

I am in:

> Google Chrome  23.0.1271.97 (Official Build 171054) m

Comment: What version of chrome? I'm not seeing this.

Comment: Oh yeah never mind, I guess I just didn't notice anything change that bothered me.

Comment: your code works as expected on the version specified, but the jsfiddle doesn't. Might be a jquery version problem?

Comment: @andho no idea what you just said...

Comment: Is `console.dir()` what you are looking for?

Comment: @twiz nope doesn't work...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update:** I made a jQuery plugin to bring back the old style logging: [jquery.chromelog](https://github.com/pimvdb/jquery.chromelog).

---

You could create a little function to log all elements on one line:

```
$.fn.log = function() {
  console.log.apply(console, this);
  return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
$("...").log();
```

Comment: @Neal: I still wasn't completely happy about it, but I noticed `console.group`. Here's a maybe more convenient one: http://jsfiddle.net/vMrka/7/.

Comment: Wow. that looks nice too. Can you add these as addendums to your answer?

Answer (score 6):

To do it for each element so that you can hover over it, try something like this:

```
$("div").each(function(){console.log(this)})​
```

Comment: Nice concise way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log($(...)[0]);
```

is another way

Comment: That'll just return the dom element.

Comment: Oh pardon me then I misunderstood that it's the DOM el he's after

Comment: What does `console.info()` give you?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a *solution* that would log them individually if need be (but it could clutter the log if it is BIG selector):

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ya7As/

```
var log = function($selector) {
    $selector.each(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
};
log($('selector'))​;
```

Comment: I'm not on Chrome at the moment, but `console.log` can log multiple things in a line, so could you try `console.log.apply(console, this);`?

Comment: @pimvdb what is `this` in this context?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the whole jQuery object. Something like `console.log.apply(console, $selector);` in this case.

Comment: @pimvdb that seemed to work! http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ya7As/2/ post as an answer ^_^