# Chrome can no longer log inspectable jQuery objects from scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console, web-inspector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I console.log a jQuery DOM Element in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974740/how-do-i-console-log-a-jquery-dom-element-in-chrome)

In the latest stable Chrome 23.0.1271.101, and Chrome Canary 26.0.1373.0, running the following code from a script:

```
$(function(){
    console.log( $('body') )
})
```

Now returns:

```
[<body>, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: #document, selector: "body"]
```

Hovering over this log out does nothing, it is not inspectable.

The interactive console still works, eg, typing:

```
console.log( $('body') )
```

Will correctly respond with:

```
[<body>...</body>]
```

When the mouse is hovered over the log output it can be inspected, as previous versions of Chrome used to do for scripts.

- Is there a way to make Chrome log inspectable elements per previous versions of Chrome, and as the interactive consol still does?
- Is there a newer or older version of Chrome which does not have this bug?

Comment: I believe the difference is whether the console is open at the time of log. I noticed the same with `[1,2]` being converted to `>Arguments` on debug tools close and reopen.

Comment: @JanDvorak Running the script with the inspector closed logs different looking output - it appears as 'jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]' rather than '[<body>, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: #document, selector: "body"]' but it still isn't inspectable.

Comment: You can expand the elements, but you won't get the DOM view. I'm still not sure if it's meant to be a BOF.

Comment: Strange, native DOM nodes seem to be lost from the reopened view _altogether_.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yep, that's what I mean: I need the DOM view.

Comment: @pimvdb Ah you're right this is a dupe. I couldn't see the other question when I searched.

Comment: I'm going to fave the dupe to notify/get notified when the Chrome dev team gets this fixed.

Comment: Don't worry, asking a dupe isn't a shame (unless your duplicate is the first thing in the related section ;-) ) and it might even net you some positive score as it serves as a potential search target.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve what Chrome previously used to do, append `[0]` to the function.

As pointed out by [JanDvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak), this may not work in all cases, and provide only the first element, but works in some cases.

```
$(function(){
    console.log($('body')[0]);
});
```

**Update**

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974740/how-do-i-console-log-a-jquery-dom-element-in-chrome), there is a jQuery plugin [jquery.chromelog](https://github.com/pimvdb/jquery.chromelog) made by [pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514749/pimvdb), which seems the way to go.

Comment: Explanation: this will log the first element instead of the whole pseudo-array. Concerning `.get()` instead of `[0]`, native arrays seem to be collapsed to just `>Array[1]` as well.

Comment: This isn't always the way to go, but it is useful in _some_ cases.

Comment: Strange, native DOM nodes seem to be lost _altogether_ when the console is closed and reopened.

Comment: @JanDvorak : Yeah, that is really wierd. I just get the object keys.

Comment: I believe this is a bug. Hold on. The no-plugin-works issue got two revisions to fix too.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, the inspector in Safari 6.0.2 (7536.26.17) still logs inspectable JQuery objects.